# Solr splitBy has no affect

Tags: solr

I want to index a DB field to multi valued field.

data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="car_type" transformer="ClobTransformer" query="select car_data from cars">
<field column="CAR_DATA"  splitBy="\$" clob="true"/>
```

schema.xml:

```
<field name="CAR_DATA" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\.|\s|\-|\~]"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /> -->
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\.|\s|\-]"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

the spiltBy has no affect and I get the value as is, But I expect to get list of values.

Comment: What is the value you're indexing?

Comment: the value from DB , for example car1~type1$car2~type2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add RegexTransformer.
try this:

```
<entity name="car_type" transformer="ClobTransformer,RegexTransformer" query="select car_data from cars">
```